# To add more than one value to paramenter in Tableau report

Tags: javascript, angularjs, tableau-api

I want to pass a list of parameters to a tableau report. Currently few websites suggest that parameters only accept a **single value** in Tableau. Is there any way i can solve my problem?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create calculated field using an if/else statement. Something like:

```
IF [Type of User] = "Premium" 
THEN 1

ELSEIF [Location] = "Florida"
THEN 1
END
```

Then drag that field in as a measure and sum it?